# Hard coding a web page to laod at a certain place

Tags: html

I am looking to hard code a html web page so upon loading goes to a set position on the page. Obviously normally it loads and starts at very top and you scroll down.

I know you can do it using link attribute but I am trying to set it forall traffic and hard code it in.

Hope you can help.

Will

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I understood what you want to do.
Here you can scroll using javascript to the bottom:
http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/page/scroll.html

If you can use ASPX you can just bring a special item into view:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.bringintoview.aspx

Like you said, you can move by using Link anchors (example below goes to anchor 5):
http://www.activevb.de/rubriken/komponenten/index-komponenten.html#anchor5

As far as I remember it was called bookmark, not anchor:
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-gcpm/#bookmark-level

Hope there is a way cou can solve it or explain it with an small example.

Regards

Comment: Your first suggestion worked perfectly. Thanks a million for your help.